# nmea_topic_driver is not publishing anything

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I created a rosbag that contains NMEA messages ([nmea_msgs/Sentence](http://docs.ros.org/api/nmea_msgs/html/msg/Sentence.html)), and I would like to generate [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) messages.

I am working on simulating time, so I run:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

Then, I play the rosbag thats contains the NMEA messages

```
rosbag play --clock nmea_gps.bag
```

Then, I start the nmea_topic_driver to generate publish [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/NavSatFix.html) on /fix topic:

```
rosrun nmea_navsat_driver nmea_topic_driver
```

Finally, when I check with rostopic if there are message on /fix topic

```
rostopic echo /fix

WARNING: no messages received and simulated time is active.
Is /clock being published?
```

Any, idea of what is going on?

I check if nmea_topic_driver was subscribed to the NMEA messages properly, and it looks fine:

```
rostopic info /nmea_sentence 
Type: nmea_msgs/Sentence

Publishers: 
 * /play_1516740862743383627 (http://MS-7A15:46035/)

Subscribers: 
 * /nmea_topic_driver (http://MS-7A15:46775/)
```

I also checked if the NMEA messages were right, and they look fine too:

```
rostopic echo /nmea_sentence 

header: 
  seq: 0
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPRMC,152545.80,A,3301.9913392,S,06053.0775644,W,0.12,0.00,261217,0.0,E,D*3F\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 1
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPGGA,152545.80,3301.9913392,S,06053.0775644,W,5,09,1.0,52.356,M,17.442,M,0.2,*72\r\
  \n"
---
header: 
  seq: 2
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPGSA,A,3,02,12,24,25,29,,,,,,,,12.0,1.7,11.8,1*29\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 3
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GLGSA,A,3,75,76,86,87,,,,,,,,,43.1,15.6,40.1,2*03\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 4
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPGSV,2,1,05,02,52,107,35,12,61,145,38,24,49,007,37,25,48,217,36,1*6A\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 5
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPGSV,2,2,05,29,47,283,41,,,,,,,,,,,,,1*55\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 6
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GLGSV,1,1,04,75,42,053,37,76,75,160,36,86,72,178,39,87,41,315,35,1*7F\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 7
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPGST,152545.80,0.090,,,,0.081,0.061,0.194*78\r\n"
---
header: 
  seq: 8
  stamp: 
    secs: 1514301945
    nsecs: 488000000
  frame_id: "GPS-RTK"
sentence: "$GPVTG,0.00,T,0.00,M,0.12,N,0.06,K,A*26\r\n"
---
```

**UPDATED: 01/24/2018**

The output of `rosnode info /nmea_topic_driver` is:

```
rosnode info /nmea_topic_driver

Node [/nmea_topic_driver]
Publications: 
 * /fix [sensor_msgs/NavSatFix]
 * /rosout [rosgraph_msgs/Log]
 * /time_reference [sensor_msgs/TimeReference]
 * /vel [geometry_msgs/TwistStamped]

Subscriptions: 
 * /clock [rosgraph_msgs/Clock]
 * /nmea_sentence [nmea_msgs/Sentence]

Services: 
 * /nmea_topic_driver/get_loggers
 * /nmea_topic_driver/set_logger_level


contacting node http://MS-7A15:34339/ ...
Pid: 28973
Connections:
 * topic: /rosout
    * to: /rosout
    * direction: outbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /nmea_sentence
    * to: /play_1516817666576416404 (http://MS-7A15:38155/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
 * topic: /clock
    * to: /play_1516817666576416404 (http://MS-7A15:38155/)
    * direction: inbound
    * transport: TCPROS
```

Thanks in advance

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280625/nmea_topic_driver-is-not-publishing-anything/) by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 56 on 2018-01-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-01-23**:
You've done a good job of debugging things so far, could you also add the output of `rosnode info /nmea_topic_driver` so I can compare it with what I'm getting?

**Comment by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) on 2018-01-24**:
did you make DEB install? if so, delete the current package and install from source. it will help.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-24**:
@0xd1ma: could you clarify a bit why the debian pkg is not working? That would help future readers decide whether your advice still applies if/when the issues you see get fixed.

**Comment by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) on 2018-01-24**:
Thanks guys for the quickly response. I updated the question with the information that you asked me. I also to remove the DEB version and installed it from source and it neither work. Any other suggestion? Is the nmea sentence that I posted correct?

**Comment by [0xd1ma](https://answers.ros.org/users/27403/0xd1ma/) on 2018-01-25**:
upload your bag file to the public repository

**Comment by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) on 2018-01-25**:
Here is the [gps_rtk_rosbag](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16kHs4YctoS9bwYDOIDOJhy3Y-dyj-tDJ/view?usp=sharing).

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-01-25**:
There's definitely something odd going on with your setup/bagfile. I can run `nmea_topic_driver` over bagfiles I've collected, and it works just fine, but when I try running it on yours, I don't get any output on `/fix`, just as you've described.

**Comment by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) on 2018-01-26**:
That is good, so there is a bug in the script that I am using for the creation of the rosbag from the nmea raw sentences (I upload the code of the script). Could you send me a few seconds of your rosbag? so I can figure it out what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The issue was solved when we removed the CR (Carriage Return) and the LF (Line Feed) control characters from the nmea sentences.

---

Originally posted by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) with karma: 56 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: -1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [minipixel](https://answers.ros.org/users/34873/minipixel/) on 2018-04-29**:
Could you please clarify how you removed those characters from the messages?

**Comment by [taihu](https://answers.ros.org/users/33402/taihu/) on 2018-04-29**:
I just deleted the characters in the gps.log file that I used to create the rosbag file.